# Contour Integral to show $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-2\pi i x\xi}}{(1 + x^2)^2}\,\mathrm{d}x = \frac{\pi}{2}(1+2\pi|\xi|)e^{-2\pi|\xi|}$.

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus

I was trying to show that when $\xi\in\mathbb{R}$, $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-2\pi i x\xi}}{(1 + x^2)^2}\,\mathrm{d}x = \frac{\pi}{2}(1+2\pi|\xi|)e^{-2\pi|\xi|}$$ with contour integration. I was able to solve it except the absolute sign around $\xi$.

---

My solution:

Let $f(z) = e^{-2\pi i z\xi}/(1+z^2)^2$. Set the contour $\gamma$ to be the semicircle with radius $R$ above the $x$-axis, i.e. $\gamma = \gamma_1 \cup \gamma_2$, where $\gamma_1 = [-R, R]$ and $\gamma_2 = Re^{i\theta}, \theta\in[0,\pi]$.

Within $\gamma$, there is a double pole of $f$ at $z = i$. By the residue theorem,
$$\int_\gamma f(z)\,\mathrm{d}z = 2\pi i \mathrm{Res}(f, i) = \frac{\pi}{2}(1-2\pi\xi)e^{2\pi\xi}.$$

As $R\rightarrow\infty$, $$\left|\int_{\gamma_2} f(z)\,\mathrm{d}z\right| \leq \int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{e^{-2\pi i R e^{i\theta}\xi}iRe^{i\theta}}{(1+R^2e^{2i\theta})^2}\,\mathrm{d}\theta\leq \int_0^\pi \frac{Re^{2\pi\xi\sin\theta}}{(R^2 - 1)^2}\leq \frac{\pi Re^{2\pi\xi}}{(R^2-1)^2} \rightarrow 0.$$

Therefore, I get $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-2\pi i x \xi}}{(1 + x^2)^2}\,\mathrm{d}x = \frac{\pi}{2}(1-2\pi\xi)e^{2\pi\xi}.$$

---

I could not figure out where the absolute value should come into place.

Comment: You have closed the contour in the upper half plane, which only works for $\xi>0$

Comment: @Giulio Thank you for your response. However, may I ask why the contour depends on the sign of $\xi$? I was wondering which step might go wrong when $\xi < 0$. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry I have made a mistake in the comment, it only works for negative $\xi$. The reason is that you want to evaluate the integral over the real line. So the extra circle you add to close the contour needs to give a negligible contribution to the integral (at least in the large $R$ limit). If $\xi <0$ and $z=x+iy$ is in the upper semicircle ($|z|=R$, $y>0$) then $|\exp(-2\pi i z \xi)|=\exp(Re(-2\pi i \xi(x+iy))=\exp(2\pi \xi y)\leq 1$. But if $\xi>0$ you cannot do the same estimate and the exponential term is actually too large. You can do a similar estimate closing the contour in $Im z<0$.

Comment: Look at $e^{iz\xi}$, if $z=a+ib$, then $e^{iz\xi}=e^{ia\xi}e^{-b\xi}$, so you want $e^{-b\xi}$ to be bounded, that is, $-b\xi\geqslant 0\rightarrow b\xi\leqslant 0$ (otherwise, as the radius of the semicircle goes to $\infty$, the value $e^{-b\xi}\rightarrow\infty$)

Comment: @Giulio Thank you so much for your explanation! I found that I missed an $R$ on the exponential when I tried to bound the integral on the semicircle, so I thought in either case the integral will vanish as $R$ gets large. Now I understand why I need to discuss the sign of $\xi$. :)

Comment: @Alessandro Thank you! I appreciate your explanation - it really makes sense.